# java-Como obtener el numero mayor de un ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

Estoy tratando de crear un `ArrayList` de números que introduce un usuario, como puedo hacer para decirle el mayor numero  de los que ha introducido ?
se que para los `Arrays` convencionales usaría un bucle `for`

del tipo algo así

```
          for(i = 0;i<num.length;i++) {
                System.out.println("Introduce un numero: ");
                num[i] = lector.nextDouble();
                numMax=num[i];  
                if (num[i]>numMax){
                    numMax = num[i];
                } 
            }
```

Pero en el caso de un `ArrayList` como seria?

Comment: El objetivo es que lo hagas sin hacer uso de dicho método, es decir, que tu misma implementes tu propio método para buscar el valor mayor.

Comment: Hola @azucarilla Sin usar ArrayList lo tenías casi terminado, solo no deberías comparar : numMax=num[i];  , revisa mi respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes usar

```html
public class MaxList {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List l = new ArrayList();
        l.add(1);
        l.add(2);
        l.add(3);
        l.add(4);
        l.add(5);
        System.out.println(Collections.max(l)); // 5
        System.out.println(Collections.min(l)); // 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!! desconocia completamente como hacer esto para arrayList!

Comment: Esto es un snippet de Java, lol.

Answer (score 1):

Lo tenias casi terminado, el problema en realidad era la comparación `numMax=num[i]` que no era necesaria, verifica los cambios:

```
int numeros = 10; //Cantidad de números a recibir mediante el teclado.
int numMax = Integer.MIN_VALUE; //mínimo valor negativo a comparar.
for(int i = 0;i< numeros ;i++) {
            System.out.println("Introduce un numero: ");
            num[i] = lector.nextInt();
            //numMax=num[i];  
            if (num[i]>numMax){
                numMax = num[i];
            } 
        }
 System.out.println("El máximo valor es: " + numMax);
```

*Esto incluso funcionaría tanto para números positivos como para negativos.

---

Otra opción es utilizar el método [Collections.max( )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-), pero este método necesita un ArrayList para obtener el elemento máximo de la colección.

> [Collections.max( )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-) Devuelve el elemento máximo de la colección
>   dada, de acuerdo con el orden natural de sus elementos.

Por lo tanto, si tienes un array de enteros llamado `num` , debes convertirlo a List para usar el método `Arrays.asList(num)` y de esta forma obtener el valor máximo.

Ejemplo:

```
  Collections.max(Arrays.asList(num));
```

ejemplo:

```
Integer[] num =  {12,122,14,18,22,1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,44,40};
System.out.println("El máximo valor es: " + Collections.max(Arrays.asList(num)));
```

Salida:

```
El máximo valor es: 122
```

---

Comment: Asignarle un valor de `0` a `numMax` solo valdrá para números que sean mayores a 0. Es decir, si se ingresa únicamente valores negativos, saldrá como valor mayor el `0`, cuando en realidad no debería ser así.

Comment: pff tienes razón no contemple números negativos, edito...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la API `collections`

```
Collections.max(arrayList);
```

Comment: Hola juan! Muchisimas gracias!! me ha servido!

Comment: Es con mucho gusto.

Answer (score 0):

```
  System.out.println("El máximo valor es: " + Collections.max(Arrays.asList(num1,num2)));
```

Comment: a solicitud del catedratico, me toco que usar dos variables diferentes dentro del mismo array y compararlos, les dejo este por si les sirve.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir una explicación de tu respuesta, **editando** la pregunta?